# How do I compare single multibyte character constants cross-platform?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, cross-platform, multibyte

As I am writing a cross-platform application, I want my code to work on both platforms.

In Windows, I use this code to compare 2 single characters.

```
for( int i = 0;  i < str.size();  i++ )
    if( str.substr( i, 1 ) == std::string( "¶" ) )
        printf( "Found!\n" );
```

Now, in Linux, the character is not found. It is found when I change the substring to a length of 2.

```
for( int i = 0;  i < str.size();  i++ )
    if( str.substr( i, 2 ) == std::string( "¶" ) )
        printf( "Found!\n" );
```

How do convert this character comparison code to be cross platform?

Comment: Which encoding do you use/expect?

Comment: I'm not sure, I didn't set any specifically. But I guess UTF-8 would be sufficient?

Comment: Ensure your code has appropriate encoding. How do you feed `str`?

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well, initially I wanted to compare char to wchar_t. But I converted into std::strings. So I use both

Comment: @Jarod42 How do I set the encoding? `std::string str = "Some string ¶ some text ¶ to see";`

Comment: @Z0q: Solutions may be different for different languages. Different sets of people follow the tags, and people who follow one tag and not the other may not want to be distracted by posts irrelevant to them. Do not waste their time. General guidance is to tag both C and C++ only when asking about differences or interactions between the languages. If you want answers for both languages, you can enter a separate question for each and cross-reference them.

Comment: @EricPostpischil alright, thank you

Comment: I suggest you use UTF-8 everywhere, and that you carefully distinguish between (potentially) un-normalized strings from "known good" normalized strings.  Then figure out if you want to normalize using NFC or NFD.  (On Windows, NFC seems to be preferred.  On Macintosh, NFD seems to be preferred.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using `str.compare()` and `size()` of character string:

```
std::string str = "Some string ¶ some text ¶ to see";
std::string char_to_compare = "¶";

for( int i = 0;  i < str.size();  i++ )
    if( str.compare( i, char_to_compare.size(), char_to_compare ) == 0 )
        printf( "Found!\n" );
```