# How do I compare single multibyte character constants cross-platform in C?

Tags: c, character-encoding, cross-platform, multibyte

In [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70771600/how-do-i-compare-single-multibyte-character-constants-cross-platform) I found a solution to do this using C++ strings, but I wonder if there would be a solution using `char`'s in C as well.

My current solution uses `str.compare()` and `size()` of a character string as seen in [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70779270/5437864).

Now, since I only use one (multibyte) character in the `std::string`, would it be possible to achieve the same using a `char`?

For example, `if( str[i] == '¶' )`? How do I achieve that using `char`'s?

(edit: made a type on SO for comparison operator as pointed out in the comments)

Comment: Use `strcmp()` to compare strings in C.

Comment: `if( str[i] = '¶' )` you assigned a value you are not doing a test

Comment: The terms *multibyte* and `char` would suggest (to me, at least) that there is a basic incompatibility in your wish. A `char` is (by definition) one byte in size.

Comment: I'm confused at "How do I achieve that using char's?". Both str[i] and '¶' are of type `char`. Perhaps you wish to assign `char foo = str[i]` and then `if (foo == '¶')`. This assumes you meant to compare rather than assign, as stated above

Comment: @MANA624: Actually, in C (but not in C++), single-quoted literals have type `int`, not `char`.

Comment: @Ôrel, this was by mistake (on SO)

Comment: A note: if you have an Unicode string, you should normalize both string before doing comparison. Unicode mandate that equivalent string must be handled as the same string, and different system may use different normalization form (e.g. Apple prefers decomposition form, most of the other systems the composition form, users tend to give not-normalized forms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I compare single multibyte character constants cross-platform in C?

You seem to mean an *integer character constant* expressed using a single multibyte character.  The first thing to recognize, then, is that in C, integer character constants (examples: `'c'`, `'¶'`) have type `int`, not `char`.  The primary relevant section of C17 is paragraph 6.4.4.4/10:

> An integer character constant has type `int`. The value of an integer character constant containing a single character that maps to a single-byte execution character is the numerical value of the representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer. **The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g.,’ab’ ), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is implementation-defined.** If an integer character constant contains a single character or escape sequence, its value is the one that results when an object with type `char` whose value is that of the single character or escape sequence is converted to type `int`.

(Emphasis added.)

Note well that "implementation defined" implies limited portability from the get-go.  Even if we rule out implementations defining perverse behavior, we still have alternatives such as

- the implementation rejects integer character constants containing multibyte source characters; or
- the implementation rejects integer character constants that do not map to a single-byte execution character; or
- the implementation maps source multibyte characters via a bytewise identity mapping, regardless of the byte sequence's significance in the execution character set.

That is not an exhaustive list.

You can certainly compare integer character constants with each other, but if they map to multibyte execution characters then you cannot usefully compare them to individual `char`s.

Inasmuch as your intended application appears to be to locate individual mutlibyte characters in a C string, the most natural thing to do appears to be to implement a C analog of your C++ approach, using the standard `strstr()` function.  Example:

```
    char str[] = "Some string ¶ some text ¶ to see";
    char char_to_compare[] = "¶";
    int char_size = sizeof(char_to_compare) - 1;  // don't count the string terminator

    for (char *location = strstr(str, char_to_compare);
            location;
            location = strstr(location + char_size, char_to_compare)) {
        puts("Found!");
    }
```

That will do the right thing in many cases, but it *still* might be wrong for some characters in some execution character encodings, such as those encodings featuring multiple shift states.

If you want robust handling for characters outside the basic execution character set, then you would be well advised to take control of the in-memory encoding, and to perform appropriate  convertions to, operations on, and conversions from that encoding.  This is largely what [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/) does, for example.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for such a well spoken answer. This gives me more than what I need to understand the situation and to point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

I believe you meant something like this:

```
char a = '¶';
char b = '¶';

if (a == b) /*do something*/;
```

The above may or may not work, if the value of '¶' is bigger than the char range, then it will overflow, causing *a* and *b* to store a different value than that of '¶'. Regardless of which value they hold, they may actually both have the same value.

Remember, the char type is simply a single-byte wide (8-bits) integer, so in order to work with multibyte characters and avoid overflow you just have to use a wider integer type *(short, int, long...)*.

```
short a = '¶';
short b = '¶';

if (a == b) /*do something*/;
```

From personal experience, I've also noticed, that sometimes your environment may try to use a different character encoding than what you need. For example, trying to print the 'á' character will actually produce something else.

```
unsigned char x = 'á';
putchar(x); //actually prints character 'ß' in console.
putchar(160); //will print 'á'.
```

This happens because the console uses an Extended ASCII encoding, while my coding environment actually uses Unicode, parsing a value of 225 for 'á' instead of the value of 160 that I want.

Comment: Thank you for answering. This seems to me like a proper solution. The only thing is that in order to get the first `short`, I would need to get the multibyte value from the `std::string`, which I may not achieve using `str[ i ]`, because it returns a `char`?

Comment: @Z0q I'm not very familiar with C++ strings, but for wide char strings I think you should use `std::wstring` instead. That way when you access an element `str[i]` you will be accessing a `wchar_t` (an unsigned short) instead of a `char`.

Comment: Thank you @Raxus, the problem is that I need cross platform support and the size of `wchar_t` is different on Windows and Linux